# How to view a DLL file on Windows XP

Tags: dll, view

i want to see the function in the dll file ,

how to view a dll file  , what tools should i use  ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI tool: **Dependency Walker**  (free download from the web)
Launch the application and File/Open desired dll.

Command line tool: **dumpbin.exe** (It came with Visual Studio, but free download might be available on msdn)

Type `dumpbin /exports desired.dll`

Answer (score 0):

try the [`DLL Export Viewer`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html)

[image]